# application for Motorola MC75

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I have a simple hello world application that target platform is set to "Windows Mobile 6 Classic Emulator", develop with Visual Studio 2008 with .NET frame 3.5. Compile and run test, everything working. Then deployed to Motorola MC75. When run, the application run fine but I cannot access the start menu, start button or the windows taskbar. I go to App Center to setup the application options not to hide start menu, still not see it. How do write an application that has taskbar, start button, and start menu display.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have MC75 siting here next to me. You should be able to see the windows logo on top Left of your Application. Clicking that will minimize your app showing you the "desktop".